# How to make a drop down list as wide as its biggest item

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a drop down (Combo Box) in MS Access that I would like to make as wide as it's biggest item. At the moment it's currently set to the following:

```
ListWidth 3.5"
ColumnWidths 1.75";1.75"
```

This is ok for values that are smaller than this but a problem occurs when longer values come in. I googled the question and found a way to dynamically make a drop down bigger [here](http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/830511-how-dynamically-set-combo-drop-down-list-width) but this seems rather complicated for what I want.

Does any one have any suggestions - like would it require iterating over the source contents, checking each individual value for its length and if its bigger than the biggest to that point - set it as the biggest and move on until the end of the values is reached.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would do a query with the SQL string

`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table ORDER BY Len(Field) Desc`

Then create a recordset, do a movefirst and finally multiply the length of the string with the size of one character.

Sorry for any fault in my text. English is not my first language.

Comment: Nice solution! (and perfect English)

Comment: seems fine - I'm going to test this now and let you know

Comment: Had a look at it - I added it to VBA and used a DAO to get the results. From that I was able to determine the length (as an integer) of the longest field value. But now I'm having a problem setting the column width - generally - I'm only now reading up about twips. Thanks for the help because you got me half way there

Comment: I think you can just add ComboBox1.ListWidth = YourCodeHere. You will maybe need to do a refresh.